# Check for a string in the user inout

Tags: python, string, user-input

I have this code but what it does is when someone types "goodmorning" or "morning" it prints "good morning" but if i were to type "hello goodmorning" it will not print good morning it will print test.
code:

```
dicmorning = "goodmorning" + "morning"
string = raw_input("test: ")
if string in dicmorning:
    print "good morning"
else:
    print "test"
```

I'm trying to make it just look for that string in the input and if it is in there then it prints "good morning". Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: If you're not sure why something isn't working, try printing your variables. Also, don't use `string` as a variable name, because it's a keyword in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check each token in the input string separately. A reasonably efficient way might be to create a set of the desired tokens, and intersect it with the input tokens...

```
dicmorning = {"goodmorning", "morning"}
raw_string = raw_input("test: ")
tokens = raw_string.split()
if dicmorning.intersection(tokens):
    print "good morning"
else:
    print "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Any raw input is a string, even if a number is entered (e.g. "2")

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more like:

```
dicmorning = ["goodmorning", "morning"]
input_string = raw_input("test: ")
foundstring = False
for i in dicmorning:
    if i in input_string:
        foundstring = True
        break
    else:
        foundstring = False
if foundstring:
    print "good morning"
else:
    print "test"
```

Though I must say that "dicmorning" isn't a good name.